# jvm in kubernetes/docker running out of memory faster than standalone

Tags: docker, java-8, kubernetes, garbage-collection

We are moving our JDK 1.8v131 JVM servers to Kubernetes/Docker environment.
We have few JVM servers running in stand alone VMs and few running Kubernetes/Docker environment and both types are present in production.
With the same load Kubernetes/Docker JVMs are running out of memory whereas JVMs in VMs are running fine without issues.
We used exact SAME JVM parameters for running in VM & Container.

Any ideas how to fix this issue?

Here are the options:

```
Environment:
      JAVA_MEM_OPTS: -Xms2048M -Xmx2048M 
                     -XX:MaxPermSize=256M -XX:+ExitOnOutOfMemoryError -agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=n,address=5005 
                     -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError 
                     -XX:HeapDumpPath=/heapdumps/${HOSTNAME}_$(date +%Y%m%d_%H_%M_%S).hprof  

      JAVA_GC_OPTS:  -Dnogclogging=true -XX:+PrintGC -XX:+PrintGCDetail
```

> 2018-12-07T15:43:21.42043862Z {Heap before GC invocations=2880 (full
>   625):  
>  2018-12-07T15:43:21.420465613Z  PSYoungGen      total
>   435712K, used 249344K   
>   **2018-12-07T15:43:21.420469712Z   eden space 249344K, 100% used**   
>  2018-12-07T15:43:21.420472561Z   from space 186368K, 0% used
>   
>  2018-12-07T15:43:21.420475332Z   to   space 228352K, 0% used
>   
>  2018-12-07T15:43:21.420477921Z  ParOldGen       total 1398272K,
>   used 1397679K   
>  2018-12-07T15:43:21.420480674Z   object space
>   1398272K, 99% used   
>  2018-12-07T15:43:21.420483127Z  Metaspace
>   used 229431K, capacity 249792K, committed 249968K, reserved 1271808K 
>   
>  2018-12-07T15:43:21.420485549Z   class space    used 24598K,
>   capacity 27501K, committed 27544K, reserved 1048576K  
>   2018-12-07T15:43:22.628605014Z 2018-12-07T15:43:21.420+0000:
>   124733.208:  ] ] 1647023K->1646334K(1833984K), ], 1.2079201 secs] [Times: user=1.98 sys=0.01, real=1.21 secs]  
>   2018-12-07T15:43:22.62868917Z Heap after GC invocations=2880 (full
>   625):  
>  2018-12-07T15:43:22.628794768Z  PSYoungGen      total
>   435712K, used 248654K   
>   **2018-12-07T15:43:22.628799885Z   eden space 249344K, 99% used**   
>  2018-12-07T15:43:22.628803713Z   from space 186368K, 0% used
>   
>  2018-12-07T15:43:22.628807485Z   to   space 228352K, 0% used
>   
>  2018-12-07T15:43:22.628811115Z  ParOldGen       total 1398272K,
>   used 1397679K   
>  2018-12-07T15:43:22.62881498Z   object space
>   1398272K, 99% used   
>  2018-12-07T15:43:22.628818943Z  Metaspace
>   used 229431K, capacity 249792K, committed 249968K, reserved 1271808K 
>   
>  2018-12-07T15:43:22.628827543Z   class space    used 24598K,
>   capacity 27501K, committed 27544K, reserved 1048576K  
>   2018-12-07T15:43:22.628831766Z }  
>  2018-12-07T15:43:22.632712004Z
>   {Heap before GC invocations=2881 (full 626):  
>   2018-12-07T15:43:22.63273803Z  PSYoungGen      total 435712K, used
>   249344K   
>   **2018-12-07T15:43:22.632742051Z   eden space 249344K, 100% used **  
>
>   **2018-12-07T15:43:22.63274617Z   from space 186368K, 0% used   
>  2018-12-07T15:43:22.632752151Z   to   space 228352K, 0% used**   
>   2018-12-07T15:43:22.632756279Z  ParOldGen       total 1398272K, used
>   1397679K   
>  2018-12-07T15:43:22.632760269Z   object space
>   1398272K, 99% used   
>  2018-12-07T15:43:22.632764456Z  Metaspace
>   used 229431K, capacity 249792K, committed 249968K, reserved 1271808K 
>   
>  2018-12-07T15:43:22.632768599Z   class space    used 24598K,
>   capacity 27501K, committed 27544K, reserved 1048576K  
>   2018-12-07T15:43:23.164683101Z 2018-12-07T15:43:22.632+0000:
>   124734.420:   
>   **SERVER RESTARTS HERE**

Answer (score 0):

Did you set your container memory resouce requests and limits?  Jdk 8u131 doesn't know that it is running inside a container.  It still sees the host VMs resources.  That could be why your JVM inside the container is killed immediately.

There's a good article from redhat back in 2017.
https://developers.redhat.com/blog/2017/03/14/java-inside-docker/

Comment: Thanks for the response, but as we are passing -Xms & -Xmx parameters JVM is not exceeding it's memory quota.

Comment: You need to set the container resource requests and limits in kubernetes. Settings xmx doesn't mean the container is using that size its only the jvm. Try setting kubernetes requests and limits.

Comment: @Bai Yes, they are also being set along with -Xms & -Xmx

Comment: We increased memory in Kubernetes / Docker environment to 3GB from 2GB and for past 4 days the JVM is running fine without any restarts.